# Conditional fields module, "OR"-like operator

Tags: 7

Can conditional fields module, or another module like it, make a field hidden/shown using an "OR"-like operator? For example,

if field A = 'yes' OR field B = 'no', then show field C.

Right now the conditional field module treats everything as an "AND" operator. For example, if field A = 'yes' AND field B = 'no', then show field C. I want field C to show up on either one of those conditions, not both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new version of the conditional fields module is taking care of this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, the [Views If Empty](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_ifempty) module could be of use to you. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ...  enables a view to output a field if another field is empty.
>
> You need Views If Empty when you have a content type with an embedded video and an imagefield thumbnail. The nodes always have the images but occasionally have a video. You want your view to display the image field when the video field is empty, display the video field when available, and never display both.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however, it seems that this works only on views.  I need something that will work on the form.